# Calculation of area in 2 definite integrals given function $y=x^2$

Tags: integration, area

Here is a graph for $y=x^2$

[image]

Given that the area in blue is equal to the area in pink, find a in terms of b and solve for a.

My attempt:

From the graph I can see that :$a^2=b$ and $a=\sqrt b$

Since area blue is equal to area in pink:

$$\int^a_1 x^2 dx=\int^b_1 y^\frac{1}{2}dy$$

$$\left[\frac{1}{3}x^3\right]^a_1=\left[\frac{2}{3}y^\frac{3}{2}\right]^b_1$$

$$\frac{1}{3}a^3-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{2}{3}b^\frac{3}{2}-\frac{2}{3}$$

$$a^3-1=2b^\frac{3}{2}-2$$

$$a^3-1=2a^3-2$$

$$a^3=1$$

$$a=1$$

The answer to $a=1$ makes sense because when $a=1$, the area becomes $0$    $units^2$

But my teacher said the answer is $a=1+\sqrt 3$
Is there any idea what has gone wrong in my calculations?
Also please tell me how to get to the answer as well?

Comment: The calculation looks fine.

Comment: If anyone else wants another go, can try.

Comment: As you saw, the pink area is always twice the blue. The only way they can be equal is if the the areas are both $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Note$$\bigg(\int_{1}^{1+\sqrt{3}} x^2 dx\bigg) -\bigg(\int_{1}^{(1+\sqrt{3})^2} \sqrt{y} dy \bigg) = -(3+2\sqrt{3}) \neq 0$$

So your teacher is wrong in this case, and you are right.

Comment: The working is my attempt, not the teacher's, but he said the answer should be $1+\sqrt3$

Comment: I have shown that your teacher's solution is incorrect. If it was right, the above expression would be $0$. Your working is fine.

Comment: Hmmm, so is $a=1$ the only answer? I guess

Comment: Indeed it is :)